# how to get the path of project directory in spring?

Tags: java, spring

i am trying to upload an image file with my jsp form. i am successfully being able to upload it but not in the directory that i want.

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {
  private Path path;
  
  @Autowired
  private ProductService productService;
  
  @RequestMapping(value="/admin/addProduct")
  public String addProduct() {
    return "addProduct";
  }
  
  @RequestMapping(value="/admin/addProduct", method= RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addNewProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product products,
  BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("prodImage") 
  MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("adding product");
        System.out.println(path);
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
      return "addProduct";
    }
    productService.saveProduct(products);
    
    MultipartFile productImage = file;
    String rootDir = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    System.out.println(rootDir);
    path = Paths.get(rootDir+"//WEB-INF//resources//images//"+products.getId()+
    ".jpg");
    System.out.println("path :"+path);
    if(productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("inside not null product image");
      try {
        productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
                System.out.println("after saving image");

      }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("product image saving failed",ex);
      }
    }
        
    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
  }
  
  @RequestMapping("/admin/productInventory")
  public String productInventory() {
    return "productInventory";
    
  }

}
```

this is the current dir location being printed:-

```
/mnt/7A46BE1454633621/eclipseworkspace/ecommerce/target/ecommerce/

  path :/mnt/7A46BE1454633621/eclipseworkspace/ecommerce/target/ecommerce/ 
WEB-INF/resources/images/5.jpg
```

i want to upload my image inside WEB-INF/resources/images. how can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to check class path is set or not then you can use `classpath:/WEB-INF/resources/images/` path to image upload and download.

Comment: how can i check class path is set or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to upload image to your images folder. Here `multipartFile` is the reference of `MultipartFile` interface

```
    InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    String path = servletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/resources/images");
    File file = new File(path);
    String basePath = file.getCanonicalPath();
    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(basePath+"/"+fileName);
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = inputStream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
```

Also to get `servletContext` reference autowire `ServeletContext` interface like this:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

Comment: Will there be a `src` directory once the application gets deployed into production?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, saving the files/photos that you got from the user to the WEB-INF folder is not a good idea. Because when you deploy your project your project will be in a kind of file jar or war. In your case, it is war probably. So jar and war are archive files and in production, you can't add some files inside of your war(archive) file. I think it is better to use a different folder for that purpose. In the development stage, you can create a folder inside of your project folder and get project dir with [system property user.dir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).